# Ошибка при обновлении базы данных Room(coroutines)

Tags: android, kotlin, room, kotlinx-coroutines

Написал приложение погоды. Логика: При старте приложения запрашивается местоположение пользователя и делается запрос на сервер, при получении ответа разбираю json и создаю дата класс City(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)). Далее делаю insert в базу данных, проверяю по имени, если города нет - то добавить, если есть - то копирую старый id и присваиваю созданному городу и далее update. Так же при старте запускается метод обновления всех городов в базе данных, который по очереди берет город, по ссылке получает новые данные и также обновляет город. В итоге получаются дубликаты городов, затирания и перемешивания. Я так понимаю это из за того, что асинхронно одновременно происходит работа с базой данных. Если отключить метод обновления городов, то все ок.
Как запустить поочереди эти запросы, или я не вижу ошибку?

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val database = App.instance.getDatabase()

private val fiveDaysWeather = MutableLiveData<String>()
private val allCities = MutableLiveData<MutableList<City>>()
fun getAllCities(): MutableLiveData<MutableList<City>> = allCities
fun getWeather(): MutableLiveData<String> = fiveDaysWeather

/** Обновление списка городов при старте приложения*/
fun updateCitiesInfo() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val citiesList = database.cityDao().getAll()
        for (city in citiesList) {
            try {
                val json = URL(city.url).readText()
                val parser = JsonParser()
                val newCity = parser.createCity(json, city.url)
                newCity.uid = city.uid
                update(newCity)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}

fun getAll() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val citiesDB = database.cityDao().getAll()
        allCities.postValue(citiesDB)
    }
}

fun insert(city: City) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val existingCity = database.cityDao().getCityByName(city.name)
            if (existingCity == null) {
                database.cityDao().insert(city)
            } else {
                city.uid = existingCity.uid
                update(city)
            }
    }
}

fun update(city: City) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        database.cityDao().update(city)
    }
}

fun delete(city: City) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        database.cityDao().delete(city)
    }
}

fun apiLoadWeather(url: String) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
        var result = ""
        val address = URL(url)
        val connection = address.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        result = when (connection.responseCode) {
            HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND -> "{\"cod\":\"404\"}"
            401 -> "{\"cod\":\"401\"}"
            429 -> "{\"cod\":\"429\"}"
            500, 502, 503, 504 -> "{\"cod\":\"500\"}"
            else -> address.readText()
        }
        fiveDaysWeather.postValue(result)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
}
```

}

```
@Entity(tableName = "city")
@TypeConverters(WeatherListConverter::class)
data class City(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var uid: Int = 0,
@ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "url") var url: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "feels_like") var feels_like: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "sunrise") var sunrise: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "sunset") var sunset: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "description") var description: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "visibility") var visibility: String,
var weatherList: List<Weather>)


@Entity
data class Weather(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
var date: String,
var temperature: String,
var pressure: String,
var humidity: String,
var wind_speed: String,
var precipitation: String,
var time:String,
var image: Int)

class WeatherListConverter {
@TypeConverter
fun fromString(value: String): List<Weather> {
    val listType = object : TypeToken<List<Weather>>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson(value, listType)
}

@TypeConverter
fun fromList(list: List<Weather>): String {
    val gson = Gson()
    return gson.toJson(list)
}
```

}

Comment: `City` тоже покажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Обновил описание @EugeneKrivenja

Comment: у вас внутри одного асинхронного кода стартует другой асинхронный. сделай "рабочие" методы suspend, оставив только 1 метод старта с viewModelScope

Comment: @Wlad Спасибо, не сразу заметил, исправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была совсем в другом месте.

```
 private fun loadWeather(url: String) {

    viewModel.apiLoadWeather(url)

    viewModel.getWeather().observe(this) { result ->
        val data = JSONObject(result)
        when (data.getString("cod")) {
            "200" -> {
                val parser = JsonParser()
                val city = parser.createCity(result, url)
                //viewModel.insert(city)
                updateInterface(city)
            }
            "404" ->
                showToast("Город не найден")

            "401" ->
                showToast("Ошибка API")

            "429" ->
                showToast("Превышен API")

            "500" ->
                showToast("Ошибка сервера")
        }
    }
}
```

С помощью этого метода, я делал запрос на сервер и ждал ответ через liveData, но пока приходил ответ, я вызывал этот метод уже с новым url. Когда приходил ответ то в аргументы создания города передавался новый url и происходило сохранение в базу данных. При перезапуске приложения города обновлялись, а так как там были чужие ссылки, то все перемешивалось и затиралось.

P.S Позже нашел ошибку в этом коде. Из за того, что слушатель был в методе, тосты показывались более 3х раз, хотя метод запускался 1 раз.